# Which op-amp for audio?

Tags: audio, operational-amplifier

I understand that the [NE5532](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NE5532-D.PDF) is an evergreen in audio applications. Which other op-amps would you consider for preamp, filter and other high fidelity audio applications?

Comment: This guy likes using OPA2134: http://sound.westhost.com/projects-2.htm

Comment: LM741 is the best for audio applications. (j/k)

Comment: Audio is such a strange segment of electronics...some of it is snake oil, some of it really works, and most of it confuses me.  They might as well use the lm741, given the fascination with tube amps.

Comment: I'm guessing this isn't closed as "primarily opinion based" because of the high reputation of the user involved in both asking and answering the question. There are literally hundreds of audio opamps that self-recommend themselves for "high fidelity audio applications". If you want figure-of-authority-tested-and-likes-X kind of arguments, there's Douglas Self's series of books.

Comment: Groner's ["Operational Amplifier Distortion"](http://www.sg-acoustics.ch/analogue_audio/ic_opamps/) is also generally aimed at audio, even though the title doesn't say that; unfortunately it doesn't cover any JRC products. NwAvGuy has an ["Op Amp Measurements"](http://nwavguy.blogspot.com/2011/08/op-amp-measurements.html) page in the same ilk, but with a much smaller selection.

Comment: It turns out there are free excerpts from one of Self's books on this issue published in *EE Times*:
["Op amps in small-signal audio design - Part 3: Selecting the right op amp"](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1278963) and ["Op amps in small-signal audio design - Part 4: Selecting the right op amp (JFET-input types reviewed)"](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1279027). So you don't have to pay to read his take on that issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*edit: What are important parameters in audio op-amps?*

First there's **noise**. All components have some level of noise and there are several types of noise. While noise levels can be very low our ears are very sensitive to it. Noise is expressed in \$V/\sqrt{Hz}\$. That's a strange unit, but can easily be explained. Noise has a continuous spectrum and is defined as power over a specific bandwidth \$W/Hz\$. To get the voltage (in a specific load) you take the square root of that.
Next there's **distortion**. Probably the most published parameter is **harmonic distortion**, and it's the one manufacturers draw the most attention on. The reason is simple: it's relatively easy to obtain spectacular-looking figures like 0.01%. But these figures are rather meaningless, because the weakest link, the speaker, often adds several procent harmonic distortion extra, and our ears aren't that sensitive to it.
Then **transient intermodulation distortion (TIM)** is far worse. It occurs when a higher frequency component modulates a lower frequency, and because their product creates non-harmonic frequencies this is much more audible. TIM was discovered rather recently because measurements were originally done with single sine waves, and then this kind of distortion can't occur. High **slew rate** op-amps have low TIM levels. Despite being much more annoying than harmonic distortion TIM levels are hardly published, because it's harder to get the same fancy looking figures as for harmonic distortion.
**Bandwidth** is also important. Op-amps have a **gain-bandwidth product (GBW)** which indicates that the bandwidth depends on the amplification; a higher gain (amplification) results in a lower bandwidth. GBW is closely related to slew-rate, and you want to have a much wider bandwidth than the 20Hz-20kHz of audio to get high slew-rate values.

---

I've found a few interesting parts at Analog Devices:

```
[OP275](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/OP275.pdf): very low noise (\$5nV/\sqrt{Hz}\$), high slew rate and low distortion  
[AD823](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD823.pdf): comparable specs, a bit higher noise
```

**edit**
Looks like I have to answer my own question... :-)
I read somewhere that the LME series is National Semiconductor's selection of high performance, high fidelity devices. You find the lot of them [on National's site](http://www.national.com/pf/master_LME.html); there's too many to list here.

Comment: Did you find much in Microchip's selection? I've heard their analog offerings are quite good. Only rumours, though.

Comment: @tyblu Microchip's offerings are great general purpose devices. I use them in a lo-fi audio application. I have no idea about high performance stuff, though.

Comment: @stevenvh, can you make this somewhat of a teaching question instead of a pure shopping one and give some details of why those specs are important in audio applications?

Comment: Unfortunately the latter part of comment can be summarized as "everything fast is best for audio", which usually is not the case, and not just from a monetary cost perspective. Fast slew rate is not free from other points of view like stability etc., which are of practical importance.

Comment: Also, regarding the claim that TIM[D] was discovered "rather recently": the papers typically cited on this, by Otala and (various) co-authors, were published in the mid 1970s, and in well-known English language venues e.g. ["Transient Intermodulation Distortion in Commercial Audio Amplifiers"](http://www.aes.org/e-lib/browse.cfm?elib=2763) [AES/1974], ["The Theory of Transient Intermodulation Distortion"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TASSP.1977.1162904) [IEEE/1977].

Comment: Quoting from "A Method for Measuring Transient Intermodulation Distortion (TIM)", published in 1977 by Otala and some co-authors: "operational amplifiers uA709, uA739, uA741, LM301, and MC1456 exhibit strong dynamic intermodulation even at low output voltages. [...] No dynamic intermodulation was found in LM318, LF356, LF357, and HA2505." So, yeah, the TIM problem was basically solved in op amps by 1977... And the NE5532 wasn't even born then.

Comment: And re 'single sine waves', IMD was commonly quoted and reviewed for audio amplifiers in the 1970s. Methods of measuring IMD are described in the Radio Designer's Handbook, 1953, and *Proc. IRE,*, 29.12.1941, and were standardized as early as 1937. Commercial devices that measure it have been available since at least 1982.

Answer (score 1):

TI has [this tool to help you choose one](http://focus.ti.com/en/download/aap/selectiontools/audio/tool.htm) and has a [selector guide](http://focus.ti.com/lit/sl/slyy013e/slyy013e.pdf). And as pointed out by @Fizz, this isn't special for TI.

Comment: Most opamp manufacturers have a selector guide and it can usually filter for audio opamps... TI isn't special in this respect.